# How to setup Mingw32 with dwimperl

Tags: perl, mingw, mingw32, ming

I installed dwimperl in windows and I want to use it with mingw32 command line.
In mingw32 there is perl version 5.8.x but i want to use perl 5.14 from mingw32. Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you really mean you want to use MinGW within Perl?

Comment: dwimperl has included mingw. you need another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dwimperl has already included the `mingw`

```
C:\Users\jm> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20111023 (prerelease) [svn/rev.180339 - mingw-w64/oz]
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

C:\Users\jm> where gcc
C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\gcc.exe
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but where is the mingw command line in the dwimperl directory? I want to also run the make, like from classic msys mingw cmd.

Comment: Hmm so i changed the PATH in my msys to dwimperl/